# CGEventPost doesn't work with backspace character on some applications

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cgeventtap

*(This question is similar to the one I recently posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10742086/cant-simulate-backspace-button-on-some-applications-with-event-tap/10742799#10742799) except that now I'm using CGEventPost to simulate more keystrokes instead of modifying current event)*

The code bellow was able to insert an 'a' character every time the 'h' button is pressed, it worked fine with all the applications.

```
CGEventRef KeyHandler(CGEventTapProxy proxy, CGEventType type, CGEventRef event, void *refcon)
{
    UniCharCount actualStringLength;
    UniCharCount maxStringLength = 1;   
    UniChar chars[3];

    CGEventKeyboardGetUnicodeString(event, maxStringLength, &actualStringLength, chars);

    if (chars[0] == 'h') {

        CGEventRef keyEventDown = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent( NULL, 1, true);
        CGEventRef keyEventUp = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent( NULL, 1, false);

        chars[0] = 'a';
        CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString(keyEventDown, 1, chars);
        CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString(keyEventUp, 1, chars);
        CGEventSetIntegerValueField(keyEventDown, kCGKeyboardEventKeycode, 0); // 0 is key code of 'a' button
        CGEventSetIntegerValueField(keyEventUp, kCGKeyboardEventKeycode, 0);

        CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, keyEventDown);
        CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, keyEventUp);
        return NULL;
    }

    return event;
}
```

If I replace 'a' with backspace character, some applications (e.g. Microsoft Excel on Mac ... ) don't recognize it anymore. Do you have any idea why ?

```
CGEventRef KeyHandler(CGEventTapProxy proxy, CGEventType type, CGEventRef event, void *refcon)
{
    UniCharCount actualStringLength;
    UniCharCount maxStringLength = 1;   
    UniChar chars[3];

    CGEventKeyboardGetUnicodeString(event, maxStringLength, &actualStringLength, chars);

    if (chars[0] == 'h') {

        CGEventRef keyEventDown = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent( NULL, 1, true);
        CGEventRef keyEventUp = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent( NULL, 1, false);

        chars[0] = '\b';
        CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString(keyEventDown, 1, chars);
        CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString(keyEventUp, 1, chars);
        CGEventSetIntegerValueField(keyEventDown, kCGKeyboardEventKeycode, 51);
        CGEventSetIntegerValueField(keyEventUp, kCGKeyboardEventKeycode, 51);

        CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, keyEventDown);
        CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, keyEventUp);
        return NULL;       
    }

    return event;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. If I remove the code to set unicode string for the events, everything will work just fine:

```
chars[0] = '\b';
CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString(keyEventDown, 1, chars);
CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString(keyEventUp, 1, chars);
```

However, I have no idea why this happens to some specific applications on Mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

The "\b" escape sequence produces ASCII 0x08. In my testing, the event generated when I press the delete (i.e. backspace) key is ASCII 0x7f.

In general, that seems the obvious technique to use to figure out how to simulate an event. Perform that event with a tool that captures it and dumps its specifics.

Comment: 0x7f is ASCII value of DEL character, not Backspace. However if I add NSLog(@"%d",chars[0]); into my code, I can see number 8 appears in console log when pressing Backspace button.

Comment: The semantics of DEL are ambiguous. Cocoa uses it to mean "delete the character prior to the insertion point", which is backspace. Cocoa uses `NSDeleteFunctionKey = 0xF728` for forward delete. Of course, you're seeing 8 when logging your own "\b". That's precisely what I said and it's precisely the problem. Write a Cocoa app which dumps the characters from `NSEvent`s that it receives and see what it logs when you press the backspace key. It will be 0x7f.

Comment: I'm seeing 8 when I purposely press Backspace button on my keyboard ;) Anyway, if value of Backspace is totally wrong as you said, how can it work with almost all other applications?

Comment: According to [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nstext_Class/Reference/Reference.html) :   NSBackspaceCharacter = 0x0008,

Comment: How did you test? I have performed the test I stated. I wrote an app using a subclass of `NSApplication` with an override of `-sendEvent:`. In the override, I do `if ([anEvent type] == NSKeyDown) NSLog(@"%#04x", [[anEvent characters] characterAtIndex:0]);`. Also, what keyboard layout are you using? I'm using the U.S. layout. With respect to those docs you linked, they also have `NSDeleteCharacter = 0x007f`.

Comment: It probably works with Cocoa applications because Cocoa does a lot of text processing on its own and treats 0x08 and 0x7f similarly. I guess it fails for Carbon apps and apps which process raw key events rather than passing them through to Cocoa's `-interpretKeyEvents:`. When coding them, the authors presumably empirically checked for the characters received in events for the key presses they wanted to handle.

Comment: I'm using default MacBook keyboard. I did the test by adding `NSLog(@"%d",chars[0]);` after the line `CGEventKeyboardGetUnicodeString(event, maxStringLength, &actualStringLength, chars);`. What I can see is that we intercepted the events at different levels, it might be the reason why we got different values.

Comment: OK, I am able to reproduce that. If I grab the `CGEvent` from an `NSEvent` and check its Unicode characters using `CGEventKeyboardGetUnicodeString()`, I get 8 for a backspace even though `-[NSEvent characters]` has 0x7f. Weird. So, looking elsewhere: why are you passing 1 to `CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent()` and then setting `kCGKeyboardEventKeycode` instead passing 51 (`kVK_Delete`) to start with? Also, can't hurt to switch the order of setting the keycode vs. the Unicode characters. Also, I'd set the source of the new events from the original. Same with `kCGKeyboardEventKeyboardType`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11854/discussion-between-huy-phan-and-ken-thomases)